# unable to get token from keycloak (cordova ios + angular app) after migrating from keycloak v10 to v13

Tags: angular, keycloak, cordova-ios

recently we are trying to migrate the keycloak for our application from v10 to v13.
during this migration, web application are working as expected however, cordova ios app build from same codebase shows following error
[image]

app works fine with keycloak V10.
are there any config required to be changed while migrating? i went through the documents however could not find anything related to this.

Comment: (re)configure web origins configuration for used client in the Keycloak.

Comment: the web origins are the same as the previous version V10, i already rechecked them.

Comment: https://github.com/jangaraj/keycloak-cors-issue-debugging

Comment: for the Cordova ios app, the origin is sent as null, any suggestions on how to handle null when it comes to web origins?

Comment: You don't have configured web origin properly, when it's null ("It is as it was before" is not an answer, I guess Keycloak now works differently). Please use full absolute url, keep in mind protol is also part of origin. Ignore stupid stackoverlfow recomendations about `*` in weborigins config. Provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - it's really not clear in your questiuon how used client is configured, how preflight request looks like, .... Only good question give your correct response.

Comment: @JanGaraj, i have uploaded the code to repo https://github.com/sanket-bhalerao/keycloak-cordova-angular. the keycloak exports for the version (v10.0.0, and v13.0.1) are under "keycloak_exports" dir in the repo.
in case the export provided gives any issue please try to use https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/examples/cordova/example-realm.json for importing. after importing when it still did not work, i added "*" in the web origin.